# Error adding component in a JDialog

Tags: java, swing, layout, netbeans, jslider

I have created a `JDialog` which has components (`JLabel`s, `JButton`s, `JTextField`s, etc), and I have another `JDialog` apart from that, that I want to have some of the components to the first `JDialog`, so in the second `JDialog` I've tried to add the components using `.add()` method, but there is a mistake when I run the program....

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout.addLayoutComponent(Unknown 
Source)
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1127)
at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:1005)
at javax.swing.JDialog.addImpl(JDialog.java:921)
at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:417)
at mainJFrame.initComponents(mainJFrame.java:721)
at mainJFrame.<init>(mainJFrame.java:30)
at mainJFrame.lambda$main$0(mainJFrame.java:1980)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I will put a part of the code, specifically the part where I receive the error.

```
   private void initComponents() {
          practiceModeConfig = new javax.swing.JDialog(this);

          //Here it supossed to go the declarations of the swings components 
          //(JLabels, Buttons,...) everything here is correct, so i dont 
          // want to put on here....

          practiceModeConfig.setUndecorated(true); 
          practiceModeConfig.setDefaultCloseOperation(
         javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
         practiceModeConfig.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(242, 176, 53));
         practiceModeConfig.setBounds(new java.awt.Rectangle(444, 308, 0, 
         0));
         practiceModeConfig.setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(400, 300));
         practiceModeConfig.getContentPane().setLayout(new 
         org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

         //This is a JSlider that i want to add in the next JDialog

         practiceModeConfig.getContentPane().add(Slider, new 
         org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(50, 410, 250, -1));

         //And this is the other JDialog....

         testModeConfig = new javax.swing.JDialog(this);
         testModeConfig.setUndecorated(true);
         testModeConfig.getContentPane().setLayout(new 
            org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());
         testModeConfig.setDefaultCloseOperation(
         javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
         testModeConfig.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(242, 176, 53));
         testModeConfig.setBounds(new java.awt.Rectangle(444, 308, 0, 
         0));
```

I want to do this with the `JSlider` component from the first `JDialog`, but I've received the mentioned error....

```
         testModeConfig.getContentPane().add(Slider, new 
         org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(50, 410, 250, -1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(50, 410, 250, -1));
```

I would guess the "-1", would be a problem.

I don't use AbsoluteLayout, but I would think that value should represent the "height" of the component.

In any case you can read the API for the AbsoluteConstraints class to find out what that parameters should be.

My real suggestion is don't use AbsoluteLayout, or the form generator of your IDE. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers, so you should be creating your forms with the layout manager (or layout managers) the will do the layout based on your requirements.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples to get you started.